# Geting Unsupported Media Type calling 3rd party API in .NET Core

Tags: .net, httpclient

I am getting Unsupported Media Type.
I think I am specifying media type as JSON, but still get the same error.

Here is my code:

```
           var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, uri);
           //custom headers
            request.Headers.Add("Custom-Signature", msg);
            request.Headers.Add("Client-Id", ClientId);

            request.Content =
                new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(pr), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            using var httpResponse = await client.SendAsync(request);
```

When I use Postman everything works.

- I need to send json as `Content-Type`.
- I also need to add Content-Length.
- Content-Type and Content-Length are mandatory fields.

Comment: Post the headers from your Postman request as well as the response headers. You said that worked fine, so we can rule some things out real quick. Also, can you provide a more detailed response from the API? How about the full request you tried to send, so we can check if the headers are correct.

Comment: The problem is solved, but not sure why it works...
If I use two separate lines request.Content = new StringContent(json); request.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json"); it works. If I use it in one line, it doesn't?!

Comment: The behavior of that constructor seems screwy but apparently it's been like that for a while. The docs do not do a good job of clearly describing the behavior when providing a `mediaType` value. Here's what I could find regarding it : https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/17036